# Why does java.util.Scanner next().charAt(0) return "{", yet my nextCharIs(scanner,"{") method returns false?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a recursive decent parser in Java and in my read Factor method, I am checking, if the next char in my scanner is "{". I use the method `nextCharIs(Scanner in, Char c)` to determine if the next char matches the pattern. In this code the next char in my scanner is "{" yet that method is returning false. `nextChar` returns "{" while `nextCharIs(in,"{")` returns false. Why is that?

```
char nextChar(Scanner in) {
    return in.next().charAt(0);
}

boolean nextCharIs(Scanner in, char c) {
    return in.hasNext(Pattern.quote(c+""));
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to call `nextChar` and `nextCharIs`? Also, is the scanner reading from `System.in` or a file or what?

Comment: The next token **starts with** {, but that doesn't mean that the next token **is** {.

Comment: The nextCharIs method only checks if the next char matches not the whole token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html): "A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a **delimiter pattern**, which **by default matches whitespace**."

Devoid of any extra layers you're operating with `scanner.hasNext(Pattern.quote("{"))`. If you further have some `new Scanner(someText);` then this is the behavior. I have to replace "{" by "x", otherwise I get problems with the markdown check here:

```
someText    hasNext(Pattern.quote("x"))
"x"         y
"xx"        n
"x "        y
"x x"       y
```

```
@Test
    public void testScan(){
        assertEquals(Collections.emptyList(), scanLBrace("x"));
        assertEquals(Collections.emptyList(), scanLBrace("{{"));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("{"), scanLBrace("{"));
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList("{", "{"), scanLBrace("{ {"));
    }


     List<String> scanLBrace(String text){
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(text);
        while (s.hasNext(Pattern.quote("{")))
        {
            result.add(s.next());
        }
        return result;
    }
```